# when will the bitcoin wallet app be available for windows phone?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, blockchain-wallet-app

I've been wondering because i just bought a windows phone and realized it doesnt have  the wallet app. any idea when windows phone will get the wallet app?

Answer (score 2):

There is no "the" wallet app.

Various development teams have produced wallet software. Some are only for certain desktop or phone platforms, and some are multiplatform. You can find a list [here](https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet). Some support Windows Phone.

As you have a Bitcoin Core related tag, there are no plans for creating a version for Windows Phone (nor for any other mobile platform).